# Use the CYCLE postgres sequence property in DJANGO auto generated ids

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, sequence, django-postgresql

I often get the error:

`error: nextval: reached maximum value of sequence "my_id_seq"`

in django autogenerated ids. Postgres is able to easily deal with this using the CYCLE attribute of sequences. 
My current solution is to do this manually with:

`ALTER SEQUENCE my_id_seq RESTART WITH 1;`

or using a custom migration. Is there a clean django way to do this?

Comment: Did you ever find a clean solution?

Comment: I wonder if the answer from this question would work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515818/django-db-migrations-renamemodel-and-autofield-sequence-name